# Distribution of peaks in permutations, after a sorting operation

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, bijective-combinatorics

Let $S_n$ be the set of permutations on $\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$.
A *peak-value* of $\pi$ is some $\pi_i$ such that $\pi_{i-1} < \pi_i > \pi_{i+1}$, where $1<i<n$. Let $PV(\pi)$ denote the set of peak-values.

A *run* of $\pi \in S_n$ is a maximal subsequence of elements in increasing order.
Given $\pi$, we can list the runs increasingly based the first entries. Let us call this operation *runsort*.
A *run* of $\pi \in S_n$ is a maximal subsequence of elements in increasing order.
For example,
$$
\mathrm{runsort}(458 \, 23 \, 6 \, 17) = 17\,23\,458\,6.
$$

O. Nabawanda and I have with [some effort](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.04220) (arxiv preprint) been able to show that
$$
 \sum_{ \pi \in S_n} t^{|PV(\pi)|} =
 \sum_{ \pi \in S_n} t^{|PV(\mathrm{runsort}(\pi))|}.
$$
We actually show that a multivariate identity (which not only keeps
track of the number of peaks, but the actual set of peak-values) holds.
We construct a bijection through a recursive process, and the bijection is not canonical.

I wonder if perhaps there is some easy bijective argument
which proves the univariate identity above, where the bijection is
natural or canonical in some sense.

Comment: I checked all the statistics on permutations in findstat, whether your set-valued equidistribution could be refined, without success.  However, I did not (yet) check statistics composed with maps.  Do you have an idea what might make sense checking?

Comment: @MartinRubey Ah, It can for sure be refined - one can refine by the set of first values in runs (before sorting). There are a few other statistics one refine with. But that might make it more complicated (perhaps)...

Comment: I made a silly mistake.  There are indeed some nice refinements.  As you say, descent bottoms, and - simultaneoiusly - the number of left to right minima and the number of occurrences of the consecutive pattern 132.  I think that this is elegant enough to be worth proving.

Comment: @MartinRubey left-to-right-minima you say, hmm... that is very interesting, I have not thought about that! Consecutive 132-patterns we observed, and I believe it is easy to include a proof of this in the framework we have.

Comment: Very limited data (all permutations of at most 9 elements) suggest that one can drop both occurrences of "number" in my previous comment, stipulating that an occurrence of a consecutive pattern 132 is defined by its middle letter.

Comment: @MartinRubey ah, yes - I have a sketch of a proof already for that... It is fairly easy to see the bijection we define in the preprint does preserve this statistic as well. The right-to-left minima (set) is also straightforward. 
Do you have some Sage code to iterate over built-in permutation statistics?

Comment: OK, would have been nice to mention this in the question, because it was some work.  Yes, there is an interface to findstat for sage, which makes this relatively painless.

Comment: @MartinRubey Sure, but by requiring more statistics to be preserved, it might be less easy to prove the identity in the question. I was hoping that there was a simpler bijection, by requiring less of it (of course, to make it canonical, one would want to impose some strong conditions)